# Is there a plugin or setting in EE6 that can randomize filename of uploaded files?

Tags: file-uploads, ee

I'm looking for a way to randomize filename of uploaded files. I've noticed in the documentation; specifically in the Legacy Reference -> File Upload Class there is a preference setting for encrypting filename.

A bit surprised there is no setting for this feature out of the box.

Comment: @aern did you solved your issue?

Comment: @ZealousWeb, Nope. Thinking of creating an extension but too complex for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Low Random](https://gotolow.com/addons/low-random), which is probably what you're looking for